# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bigPoster'). How to correct?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bigPoster')

```
async getCollections(): Promise<ICollection[]> {
        const genres = await this.getAll()
        const collections = await Promise.all(
            genres.map(async (genre) => {
                const moviesByGenre = await this.movieService.byGenres([genre._id])
                const result: ICollection = {
                    _id: String(genre._id),
                    title: genre.name,
                    slug: genre.slug,
                    image: moviesByGenre[0].bigPoster,
                }
                return result
            })
        )
        return collections
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) feature, which appear in the `ES2020` version of JavaScript.

This error appears because in your code, you may have a time when your `moviesByGenre` array is empty. And if its the case, you don't have any poster in it. So, you can't get the `bigPoster` key in the `undefined` value.

The notation `?.` will return undefined instead of an error if your array is empty.

```js
async getCollections(): Promise<ICollection[]> {
        const genres = await this.getAll()
        const collections = await Promise.all(
            genres.map(async (genre) => {
                const moviesByGenre = await this.movieService.byGenres([genre._id])
                const result: ICollection = {
                    _id: String(genre._id),
                    title: genre.name,
                    slug: genre.slug,
                    image: moviesByGenre[0]?.bigPoster,
                }
                return result
            })
        )
        return collections
    }
```